# XCode FacebookSDK Framework Search Path

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am develoing an IOS application. I am using FacebookSDK for login. we have 3 developers working on project. Also we using git subversion. I added facebookSDK to project, and also unchecked "Copy items into destination group's folder(if needed)". But Other developers pull to project and faceook SDK has failed them. What should I do write to Framework Search Path

```
$(SRCROOT) :    /dev/workplace/applications/myapp

My Project Sorce Path :    /dev/workplace/applications/myapp

My FacebookSDK folder path :     /Users/Ari.Fon/Documents/FacebookSDK
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write `/Users/$(USER)/Documents/FacebookSDK` to Framework Search Path.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> I **FINALLY** learn how to do it in the easy way. so for others :
>  1. Go to build setting - framework search path
>  2. Tap on the value fields, this will open windows with + - buttons (don't use them)
>  3. Now the MAGIC, go to Finder and drag the FacebookSDK folder to that window
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I stumble to this issue today and the best solution for me was to add:
"$(SRCROOT)/YourProjectName/FacebookSDKFolder/FacebookSdk"

Important: use the quotes when adding this search path or it won't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having issues with implementing multiple framework search paths like I did, heres how I solved it

Under framework search paths, there is a + sign which allows you to add multiple framework search paths.

Copy /Users/$(USER)/Documents/YourFrameworkName and add accordly.